# Getting maximum out of ng-repeat = 'item in items'

Tags: angularjs

```
ul
 li(ng-repeat='item in index')
  a(href='{{item}}') link is {{item}}
```

In Controller

```
$scope.index= ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

$scope.alphabets= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'dates']
```

The above works, but we can only use `{{item}}` in the html page.  So both `href` and `<a> tag` contain `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Double evaluation of `{{}}` in `{{alphabets[{{item}}]}}` does not work.

I want to do:

```
li(ng-repeat='item in index')
 a(href='alphabets[{{item}}]') fruits[{{item}}]
```

which shows

```
a(href='a') apple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to "nest" the expressions. The index access can go in the same expression: `{{fruits[$index]}}`

```
li(ng-repeat='item in index')
 a(href='{{alphabets[$index]}}') {{fruits[$index]}}
```

By the way, why do you model the data like that. Seems to be a little hacky. Wouldn't it be better to just create an array of objects?

```
$scope.items = 
  [{letter: 'a', fruit: 'apple'}, {letter: 'b', fruit: 'banana'} /*etc.*/]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it more simple with the $index property (that is the index of the item in ng-repeat.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in index">
      <li><a href="{{alphabets[$index]}}">{{fruits[$index]}}</a></li>
</ul>
```